# Can I use new React Native architecture with libraries which doesn't support it

Tags: react-native

This year React Native team introduced new architecture https://reactnative.dev/blog/2022/03/15/an-update-on-the-new-architecture-rollout. This functionality is still under the flag but for me is not clear, can I use all libraries which working with old bridge with this new architecture?

I haven't found answer in the official documentation. Only thig I found is a list of libraries which support new architecture. https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-new-architecture/discussions/6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what type of a library it is. Library maintainers can add support for both architectures.

You can find a compatibility table in [this readme](https://github.com/kelset/react-native-new-arch-limits).

[image: Compatibility table https://github.com/kelset/react-native-new-arch-limits]

Comment: thank you. could you add your opinion in general, please?

Comment: Opinion on what exactly @arkan4ik92?